# Salesforce Instance Type Required

Tags: community, platform-event, type, instance

We are using Salesforce OAuth webserver flow to connect with external salesforce system. To have a valid ClientId and ClientSecret we need to order a Salesforce instance. Can you please guide which kind of Salesforce instance we would need to create a connected app and have client Id/Secret (run OAuth webserver flow).

There are are many options like Sales, Platform, Community etc. We need to chose one of these.

Comment: Sales Cloud or Platform are license types (also names of Salesforce product lines that translate into license types). The answer to your question depends on what you're trying to accomplish via access to Salesforce.  Please edit your question and provide more information on your goals.

Answer (score 0):

Just to get a connected app working you can simply sign up a [Developer Edition org](https://developer.salesforce.com/signup).

Because it is a free instance, make sure you review the [MSA](https://trailblazer.me/resource/1637114895000/TermsOfUse_en_US) and the [Terms of Use](https://www.salesforce.com/content/dam/web/en_us/www/documents/legal/salesforce_Developer_MSA.pdf) before using it for commercial or production purposes.

If you are looking to market this app on AppExchange you will need to work to sign up as a [partner](https://partners.salesforce.com/s/education/consultants/Consulting_Partner_Signup).

To learn more about what license you need I suggest you directly [contact Salesforce](https://www.salesforce.com/company/contact-us/) and meet with an Sales to discuss your need.

Comment: We want to use it for commercial and production purposes. For basic testing we used Developer Edition Org. Now we want to product-ionize our solution hence wondering what kind of instance we would need with mentioned requirements.

Comment: Sign up for a Salesforce partner program and learn about ISV Program from Salesforce. https://partners.salesforce.com/pdx/s/learn?language=en_US